# .Net iOS Issue " GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources'"

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im migrating Xamarin.iOS project to .Net iOS project but facing an issue while using a maps package.

Steps:

Created a New .Net iOS project

Installed latest package of  Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps 6.0.1.1

Open Appdelegate.cs

Add code

```
MapServices.ProvideApiKey(<API key>); 
MapServices.SharedServices;
```

Once I run the app in iPhone device, i'm getting the error as
Message (ObjCRuntime.ObjCException) "Objective-C exception thrown. Name: GMSServicesException **Reason: Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources'**

The above code is working in simulator but not on device. Is there any workaround for this?

I cound not degrade to lower maps nuget versions as the lower version dont have support for .net in their framework.

Comment: Did it work well on physical device using Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: Yes, its working fine on Xamarin.iOS, but the issue happening on .Net iOS

Comment: You could also follow this thread on GitHub: [.Net iOS Issue " GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources'"](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/631).

Comment: Following but that was also create be me :)

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue and fixed it by installing the following package via NuGet:

Xamarin.Build.Download